# Unable to Subscribe to Redis Channel Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5, phpredis

I am following Laravel office Redis guide but i am having some problem
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/redis#pubsub

After creating the command when i run " -> php artisan redis:subscribe" in console i get following error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "redis" namespace.
```

I am unable to listen to Redis Chanel.

Redis Publish Channel method is working fine. To check this.
In console I typed "-> redis-cli" and then "subscribe mychannel"
On refreshing browser I am getting publish data in console.

I am unable to subscribe via Laravel.

I also tried using wild card

```
Route::get('/subscribe', function()
{
  Redis::psubscribe(['*'], function($message, $channel) {
      echo $message;
  });
});
```

but browser keep loading and i don't get any data.
I also tried making a method in controller

```
public function subscribeChannel()
{
    $redis = Redis::Connection();
    $redis->subscribe(['channel'], function($message) {
        echo $message;
    });
}
```

This subscribeChannel method gives me following error

```
ErrorException in StreamConnection.php line 390:
strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

My configuration in config/database.php is folowing

```
'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'read_write_timeout' => 0
        ],
    ],
```

Looking for help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Redis::connection & then subscribe not working for Laravel 5.2.

You can use following command for the same:

```
Redis::subscribe(['user_online_offline'], function ($message) {
      echo $message;
});
```

If you want to use another connection for the same then you can use following command:

```
Redis::subscribe(['user_online_offline'], function ($message) {
     echo $message;
}, $connection = 'socket');
```